# AngularJS - creating a service object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Instead of posting in Angular mailing list, I think this may be more of javascript question. Hope the SO community can also give faster response.

I am trying to encapsulate the data in a service and injecting into controller.

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Player', function($resource){
        var Player ;
        Player = {
            resource: $resource('/api/Player/:_id', {} )
        };
        return Player
});


function PlayerDetailCtrl(Player, $routeParams, $scope) {
    $scope.resource = Player.resource.get({_id:$routeParams._id});
}
PlayerDetailCtrl.$inject = ['Player', '$routeParams', '$scope'];
```

It throws an exception

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'query'
```

`$scope.resource = Player.Player.resource.get({_id:$routeParams._id});` also throws error

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'query'
```

the below works.

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Player', function($resource){
        var Player ;
        Player= $resource('/api/Player/:_id', {} )
        return Player
});


function PlayerDetailCtrl(Player, $routeParams, $scope) {
    $scope.resource = Player.Player.get({_id:$routeParams._id});
}
PlayerDetailCtrl.$inject = ['Player', '$routeParams', '$scope'];
```

my intention is to add more data and method to `Player`. So how can I make the first (object form) works!

Comment: Interesting. Is `Player: $resource('/api/Player/:_id', {} )` valid javascript?

Comment: extemely sorry, was editing meanwhile. it works if I assign to a variable and access through it, but not if assign inside an object. thanks

Comment: @GraceShao `Player: $resource('/api/Player/:_id', {} )` yes if it's part of a member definition ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a factory, this is the atypical way of doing. You don't want to be returning an instance. Angular will give you an instance in your controller.

```
 factory('Player', function ($resource) { 
    return $resource('/api/Player/:_id', { });
 })
```

Here is a service I wrote to interact with a cakephp REST service. I wrote it a while back so just take it as an illustration, I may refactor.

```
 factory('CommentSvc', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/cakephp/demo_comments/:action/:id/:page/:limit:format', { id:'@id', 'page' : '@page', 'limit': '@limit' }, {
      'initialize' : { method: 'GET', params: { action : 'initialize', format: '.json' }, isArray : true },
      'save': { method: 'POST', params: { action: 'create', format: '.json' } },
      'query' : { method: 'GET', params: { action : 'read', format: '.json' } , isArray : true },
      'update': { method: 'PUT', params: { action: 'update', format: '.json' } },
    });
```

}).

Comment: Dan, I recognize your name from angular mailing list :-). I wanted to add some custom methods to the service. I could create another and inject as well, but was wondering whether I could avoid creating a service just to return a resource object, but encapsulate more related functionality. What you think?

Comment: not sure I understand, you can add any custom methods you want to a resource object, if the default ones don't meet your needs

Comment: um. I was adding non resource function to this factory/service. For example, caching the get request response initially, and setting it to $scope in controllers. May be an anti-pattern, but I am still learning.

Comment: You can inject services into other services so you can get reuse there.  I wrap resource objects to make app testable and flexible.

Comment: I posted a message in angular mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/hgUGrg5yeis

Comment: Great. injecting service to another is better. thanks for suggesting. Please share your thought on my post in mailing list. thank you.

Comment: Hey Dan, Thanks for this brilliant piece of code. Works absolutely fine. Im trying to canche the data into a cache factory and just not able to get it to work. So basically i want it to get the data once and cache it and every subsequent query shud be served from cache. Do you have any example of such code?

Comment: @bsr great question. With the release of 1.2 the angular team has made it easier to replace/extend modules therefore it would be an accepted practice. ng-resource has pretty much always been separate. You could extend ng-resource or (write your own) and namespace it with your own name. Best not to use same 'ng-resource' name. This would give you the ability to have your own encapsulated functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JS is complaining about some code for Player. I guess `Player= $resource('/api/Player/:_id', {} )` makes `Player` have a property call `query`. The form you changed to does not make `Player` have that property.

Comment: I am still learning JS, so trying to figure out why. How it different if wrap in an object?

Comment: if you look into the function `$resource`, it might have `query` as a property of the return object. But you changed to `{
            resource: $resource('/api/Player/:_id', {} )
        }`, which does not have the property called `query`

Comment: so, doesn't it allow to chain the methods?

Comment: what do you mean by chaining the methods in your context?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after few tries the following worked.

```
Player = {
            resource: function() {
                     return $resource('/api/Player/:_id', {} )
            }
        };
```

In this I explicitly return resource object. But cannot explain how it differ from

`resource: $resource('/api/Player/:_id', {} )`