# Angular Resource Update not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I've built 2 factories for my 2 data types Act and Scene. Everything works perfectly except my Scene's update function (create, read, delete work fine). For the life of me i cannot figure out what the Scenes-update function is not working, i just get this message:

```
TypeError: Object function Resource(value){
        copy(value || {}, this);
      } has no method 'update'
    at Object.ScenesUpdateCtrl.$scope.save
```

I've got 2 factories:

```
app.factory('ActsService', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/acts/:id', {id: '@id'}, {update: {method: 'PUT'}});
});

app.factory('ScenesService', function($resource) {
  $resource('/api/scenes/:id', {id: '@id'}, {update: {method: 'PUT'}});
  $resource('/api/scenes/:actId', {actId: '@id'}, {query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}});
  $resource('/api/scenes/:actId/:id', {actId: '@actId', id: '@id'}, {get: {method: 'GET'}});
  return $resource('/api/scenes/:actId/:id', {actId: '@actId', id: '@id'}, {delete: {method: 'DELETE'}}); 
});
```

And some controllers to handle all the Update operations.

```
function ActsUpdateCtrl ($scope, $location, $routeParams, ActsService) {
  var id = $routeParams.id
  $scope.act = ActsService.get({id: id})
  $scope.action = "Update"

  $scope.save = function() {
    ActsService.update({id: id}, $scope.act, function() {
      $location.path('/admin/acts')
    })
  }
}

function ScenesUpdateCtrl ($scope, $location, $routeParams, ScenesService) {
  var id = $routeParams.id
  var actId = $routeParams.actId
  ScenesService.get({actId: actId, id: id}, function(resp){
    $scope.scene = resp
    $scope.actId = resp.PartitionKey
        $scope.prev = resp.prev.split(",")
  })
  $scope.scenes = ScenesService.query({actId: actId})

  $scope.action = "Update"

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.scene.prev = $scope.prev
    ScenesService.update({id: id}, $scope.scene, function() {
      $location.path('/admin/acts/' + $scope.actId)
    })
  } 
}
```

Act works, Scene throws the before mentioned error message.

Comment: Easier to debug these things in a plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.
[AngularJS - creating a service object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251181/angularjs-creating-a-service-object)

Found a way to write it, so that it works, not sure why it works, but as along as it works i'm happy.

```
app.factory('ScenesService', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/scenes/:actId/:id', { actId : '@actId', id:'@id' }, {
    update: {method: 'PUT'},
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
    get: {method: 'GET'},
    delete: {method: 'DELETE'}
  })  
});
```